# Waiting for operation to finish in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm new to Node.js. I'm trying to use the Node [Redis plugin](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). What I'm trying to do is get the list of key/value pairs from a REDIS database. The asynchronous nature of Node is creating a challenge for me. When I try to print the key/value pairs, my array is empty. I think its because my query to the database hasn't completed yet.

The reason I'm creating an array first instead of just printing out the key/value pairs, is because I want to sort the results alphabetically by either key or value. Currently, I"m trying the following:

```
redisClient.on('connect', function() {
  var pairs = [];
  redisClient.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
      (function(key) {
        redisClient.get(key, function(err, v) {
          pairs.push({ key: key, value: v });
        });
      })(keys[i]);
    }
  });

  // List of key/value pairs ordered alphabetically
  console.log(pairs);
});
```

Can someone tell me how to get beyond this issue? Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. look up "node asynchronous code", find a promise library, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in your assertion that when `console.log` is executed, nothing has happened yet. To deal with this kind of problem in Node.js, some people like to use modules like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and others prefer to use promises (a popular library for promises is [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)).

Here is a solution using async.

```
var async = require('async');

redisClient.on('connect', function() {
  redisClient.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }

    async.map(keys, function(key, callback) {
      redisClient.get(key, function(err, value) {
        callback(null, {key: key, value: value});
      });
    }, function(err, pairs) {
      console.log(pairs);
    });
  });
});
```

async just happens to have a [`map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map) function that takes an array, applies a function asynchronously to each elements and creates an array with the results.

Comment: Doesn't this still have the same problem though? Doesn't this code race through the loop while requests to the REDIS database are being made? For that reason, doesn't done get executed before all of the key values are retrieved?

Comment: Yes, you're completely right. This doesn't solve the issue at all. Give me a few minutes and I'll come up with a proper solution.

Comment: I hate to keep pestering you. However, now when I run console.log(pairs) as shown above, it just shows '[ undefined ]'. However, if I print the key/value before the callback({key:... line, they are returned correctly. For some reason, they're not getting added to the pairs array. Do you know why? Thank you for your persistence.

Comment: @user3284007 oops, yes. Try now, I've updated the code inside the `redisClient.get` callback. That's what I get from trying to write code without testing it

Comment: OH!!! I see how it works now. Thank you so much for your help and persistence. I was totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion:

```
do = function(i, data, callback){
    // if the end is reached, call the callback
    if(data.length === i+1)
       return callback()
    obj = data[i]
    redisClient.get(key, function(err, v) {
      pairs.push({ key: key, value: v });
      i++;
      // call do with the next object
      do(i, data, callback)
    });

}
// Redis...
do(0, keys, function(){
    // List of key/value pairs ordered alphabetically
    console.log(pairs);
});
```